# What is the char that is displayed over hidden passwords?

Tags: passwords, char, ascii

If you type a password in a modern application, it usually displays a nice neat black circle - where more traditional app's would use an asterisk. How is that character created? Is it an ascii value (if so I can't find it)? If not, how is it created?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[U+25CF BLACK CIRCLE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25cf/index.htm): ●

Answer (score 5):

At least for android [this one](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm) is the correct one •

\u2022 or U+2022

Answer (score 1):

Firefox for instance uses mainly two variations internally:

- For Windows they use ● ['BLACK CIRCLE' (U+25CF)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25cf/index.htm). ([as seen here](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/e62f3ab43146d93eeae7a5f95fa878d464715deb/widget/windows/nsLookAndFeel.cpp#L696))
- For Mac and Android they use • ['BULLET' (U+2022)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm). ([as seen here](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/ecd91b104714a8b2584a4c03175be50ccb3a7c67/widget/uikit/nsLookAndFeel.h#L25))

For Linux they use the systems internal ["invisible-char"](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/property.Entry.invisible-char.html), not quite sure which character that is.